# Are Elixir variables really immutable?

Tags: immutability, elixir

In Dave Thomas's book Programming Elixir he states "Elixir enforces immutable data" and goes on to say:

> In Elixir, once a variable references a list such as [1,2,3], you know it will always reference those same values (until you rebind the variable).

This sounds like "it won't ever change unless you change it" so I'm confused as to what the difference between mutability and rebinding is. An example highlighting the differences would be really helpful.

Comment: It's shadowing, not reassignment.

Comment: shadowing *is* reassignment in the same function body ...afraict

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Immutability means that data structures don't change. For example the function `HashSet.new` returns an empty set and as long as you hold on to the reference to that set it will never become non-empty. What you *can* do in Elixir though is to throw away a variable reference to something and rebind it to a new reference. For example:

```
s = HashSet.new
s = HashSet.put(s, :element)
s # => #HashSet<[:element]>
```

What *cannot* happen is the value under that reference changing without you explicitly rebinding it:

```
s = HashSet.new
ImpossibleModule.impossible_function(s)
s # => #HashSet<[:element]> will never be returned, instead you always get #HashSet<[]>
```

Contrast this with Ruby, where you can do something like the following:

```
s = Set.new
s.add(:element)
s # => #<Set: {:element}>
```

Comment: So is rebinding like local-only mutability? Within a block you can rebind a variable but once out of scope the variable is goes back to its original value - is that right?

Comment: Local-only - yes. But when the variable goes out of scope, then it simply stops existing. The data that variable pointed to doesn't necessarily (might for example be returned from the function) and that data is immutable.

Comment: If you want immutable variables you need to use Erlang or prefix the Elixir variable with `^`. Rebind is just a fancy term in Elixir to hide that a variable is indeed mutable. To bear in mind that I love Elixir, but I really don't like when the community try to hide the mutability of the variables behind fancy terms and explanations.

Comment: @Exadra37 Not so. You can think of the pin operator `^` in an expression as just substituting the variable with it's value. This operator finds most of it's use in pattern matching etc. As for immutability, yes for all intents and purposes, Elixir is indeed immutable. If one intends to change the value of a variable, the value stored in the location pointed to by that variable cannot itself be mutated to another value. Instead the variable is rebound to a new location which can store the new value. Hence the term "rebind."

Comment: @sri I don't care about the implementation details, aka how the core works, I care about the Interface, aka how it can be used, thus If I can use the same variable twice and get a different value, then for me that is not immutable, instead is mutable. Now you can come with all the technical explanations you want, and I know a lot of them, but that will never change that the Elixir API to use variables is allowing for mutable variables, but the Erlang API for using variables only allows for immutable variables.

Comment: @Exadra37 elixir variables are not mutable, as rebinding a variable is simply reusing a variable name: it refers to a different memory location, and **any code coming before the rebind will still refer to the old value, even if run afterwards**. Mutability as a concept refers to a value in memory, rather than which value is referenced. You can think of elixir's rebinding as a compile-time trick that (at and after rebinding) will rename a variable so that the VM does not attempt to assign a value to an already-assigned variable (this is effectively how the Elixir compiler behaves).

Answer (score 105):

Don't think of "variables" in Elixir as variables in imperative languages, "spaces for values". Rather look at them as "labels for values".

Maybe you would better understand it when you look at how variables ("labels") work in Erlang. Whenever you bind a "label" to a value, it remains bound to it forever (scope rules apply here of course).

In Erlang you *cannot* write this:

```
v = 1,      % value "1" is now "labelled" "v"
            % wherever you write "1", you can write "v" and vice versa
            % the "label" and its value are interchangeable

v = v+1,    % you can not change the label (rebind it)
v = v*10,   % you can not change the label (rebind it)
```

instead you must write this:

```
v1 = 1,       % value "1" is now labelled "v1"
v2 = v1+1,    % value "2" is now labelled "v2"
v3 = v2*10,   % value "20" is now labelled "v3"
```

As you can see this is very inconvenient, mainly for code refactoring. If you want to insert a new line after the first line, you would have to renumber all the v* or write something like "v1a = ..."

So in Elixir you can rebind variables (change the meaning of the "label"), mainly for your convenience:

```
v = 1       # value "1" is now labelled "v"
v = v+1     # label "v" is changed: now "2" is labelled "v"
v = v*10    # value "20" is now labelled "v"
```

**Summary:** In imperative languages, variables are like named suitcases: you have a suitcase named "v". At first you put sandwich in it. Than you put an apple in it (the sandwich is lost and perhaps eaten by the garbage collector). In Erlang and Elixir, the variable is not **a place** to put something in. It's just **a name/label** for a value. In Elixir you can change a meaning of the label. In Erlang you cannot. **That's the reason why it doesn't make sense to "allocate memory for a variable" in either Erlang or Elixir, because variables do not occupy space. Values do.** Now perhaps you see the difference clearly.

If you want to dig deeper:

1) Look at how "unbound" and "bound" variables work in Prolog. This is the source of this maybe slightly strange Erlang concept of "variables which do not vary".

2) Note that "=" in Erlang really is not an assignment operator, it's just a match operator! When matching an unbound variable with a value, you bind the variable to that value. Matching a bound variable is just like matching a value it's bound to. So this will yield a *match* error:

```
v = 1,
v = 2,   % in fact this is matching: 1 = 2
```

3) It's not the case in Elixir. So in Elixir there must be a special syntax to force matching:

```
v = 1
v = 2   # rebinding variable to 2
^v = 3  # matching: 2 = 3 -> error
```

Comment: @DavidC: These are two questions: 1. Is it possible/imagineable? 2. Is it a good idea?
I think the answer for 1 is "yes" and for 2 "no". There are very good functional mechanisms (map, reduce,...) which are better suited imho. But this question is broad and probably can't be answered right in few words :)

Comment: @MiroslavPrymek at point 3 of your answer, is there cases in Elixir where matching would be strictly forced?

Comment: @simo No I am aware of. The manual also doesn't say anything like that: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html

Comment: `x = x +1` hurts my maths brain. Erlang stops that headache and Elixir doesn't. :(

Comment: @KevinMonk It’s something you have to get used to in programming

Answer (score 46):

Erlang and obviously Elixir that is built on top of it, embraces immutability.
**They simply don’t allow values in a certain memory location to change.** Never Until the variable gets garbage collected or is out of scope.

Variables aren't the immutable thing. The data they point to is the immutable thing. That's why changing a variable is referred to as rebinding.

You're point it at something else, not changing the thing it points to.

`x = 1` followed by `x = 2` doesn't change the data stored in computer memory where the 1 was to a 2. It puts a 2 in a new place and points `x` at it.

`x` is only accessible by one process at a time so this has no impact on concurrency and concurrency is the main place to even care if something is immutable anyway.

Rebinding doesn’t change the state of an object at all, the value is still in the same memory location, but it’s label (variable) now points to another memory location, so immutability is preserved. Rebinding is not available in Erlang, but while it is in Elixir this is not braking any constraint imposed by the Erlang VM, thanks to its implementation.
The reasons behind this choice are well explained by Josè Valim [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/josevalim/ce2f5871a96b6cbcf2c1) .

Let's say you had a list

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
```

and you had another process that was taking lists and then performing "stuff" against them repeatedly and changing them during this process would be bad. You might send that list like

```
send(worker, {:dostuff, l})
```

Now, your next bit of code might want to update l with more values for further work that's unrelated to what that other process is doing.

```
l = l ++ [4, 5, 6]
```

Oh no, now that first process is going to have undefined behavior because you changed the list right? Wrong.

That original list remains unchanged. What you really did was make a new list based on the old one and rebind l to that new list.

The separate process never has access to l. The data l originally pointed at is unchanged and the other process (presumably, unless it ignored it) has its own separate reference to that original list.

What matters is you can't share data across processes and then change it while another process is looking at it. In a language like Java where you have some mutable types (all primitive types plus references themselves) it would be possible to share a structure/object that contained say an int and change that int from one thread while another was reading it.

In fact, it's possible to change a large integer type in java partially while it's read by another thread. Or at least, it used to be, not sure if they clamped that aspect of things down with the 64 bit transition. Anyway, point is, you can pull the rug out from under other processes/threads by changing data in a place that both are looking at simultaneously.

That's not possible in Erlang and by extension Elixir. That's what immutability means here.

To be a bit more specific, in Erlang (the original language for the VM Elixir runs on) everything was single-assignment immutable variables and Elixir is hiding a pattern Erlang programmers developed to work around this.

In Erlang, if a=3 then that was what a was going to be its value for the duration of that variable's existence until it dropped out of scope and was garbage collected.

This was useful at times (nothing changes after assignment or pattern match so it is easy to reason about what a function is doing) but also a bit cumbersome if you were doing multiple things to a variable or collection over the course executing a function.

Code would often look like this:

```
A=input, 
A1=do_something(A), 
A2=do_something_else(A1), 
A3=more_of_the_same(A2)
```

This was a bit clunky and made refactoring more difficult than it needed to be. Elixir is doing this behind the scenes, but hiding it from the programmer via macros and code transforms performed by the compiler.

[Great discussion here](https://www.reddit.com/r/elixir/comments/2o1sax/how_is_elixir_immutable_if_it_lets_you_mutate/)

[immutability-in-elixir](http://selfrecursion.com/2015/05/16/immutability-in-elixir/)

Comment: +1 very clear answer. It explains very well which is the compiler technique underlying the immutability and its reasons.
This answer together with the Prymek's answer finally let me have a good understanding of this matter. They both should be part of the official Elixir documentation.

Comment: @subhash so are you saying when you do `x = 1; f = fn -> x end; x = 2; #=> 2` in Elixir, the `f` lambda doesn't even access the x variable through `x` but rather a secondary reference? Is that how it's able to still access the 1 even though x gets set to 2? I realize part of this comes from elixir immediately compiling it, but that fact aside, is there a secondary reference that is used to access data even after rebinding takes place?

Comment: this answer among others here have biggest effort to explain the topic

Comment: This is the good explanation for me! Variables are the mutable thing in Erlang, the key is understanding that Erlang enforces each variable to be used by just the thread it created it, so no concurrency can happen in that mutable thing.

Comment: great post, it's clear enough, especially:  Elixir is doing this behind the scenes, but hiding it from the programmer via macros and code transforms performed by the compiler.

Answer (score 5):

The variables really are immutable in sense, every new rebinding (assignment) is only visible to access that come after that. All previous access, still refer to old value(s) at the time of their call.

```
foo = 1
call_1 = fn -> IO.puts(foo) end

foo = 2
call_2 = fn -> IO.puts(foo) end

foo = 3
foo = foo + 1    
call_3 = fn -> IO.puts(foo) end

call_1.() #prints 1
call_2.() #prints 2
call_3.() #prints 4
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it a very simple

variables in elixir are not like container where you keep adding and removing or modifying items from the container.

Instead they are like Labels attached to a container, when you reassign a variable is as simple a you pick a label from one container and place it on a new container with expected data in it.