# Fill a List with a for-loop

Tags: for-loop, elixir

Why can't I fill a list with this simple for-loop?

```
new_data = []
for data <- old_data do
  new_data = List.insert_at(new_data, -1, data)
end
```

After this operation my `new_data` list is still empty, even though the loop is N times executed.

Comment: It's wise to remember that in functional programming in general _everything_ is an expression.  As @Gazler points out below, you can directly assign the result of the comprehension to a value so you don't need to do the "initialize the value to an empty value and then assign it" pattern.

Comment: By the way, this isn't an Erlang question.  I'm removing the erlang tag from this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Elixir, you can't mutate the value your variable is referencing as explained in [Are Elixir variables really immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967086/are-elixir-variables-really-immutable). For in this instance is not a "loop" it is a [list comprehension](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html).

You can assign to the result of a comprehension with:

```
new_data = for data <- old_data do
  data
end
```

In your line:

```
new_data = List.insert_at(new_data, -1, data)
```

The `new_data` variable is local to the scope of the comprehension. You can use your previous `new_data` value, but you won't be able to rebind for the outside scope. Which is why `new_data` is still `[]` after your comprehension. The scoping rules are explained in http://elixir-lang.readthedocs.org/en/latest/technical/scoping.html

Comment: This is interesting. Thank you. I knew the variables are unmutable. But I thought if I declare the list befor I can rebind it.

Comment: Thank you! This took me way too long to figure out.