# How can I do multiple global variable edit inside a function?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am new in elixir &using iex for testing some code portability from MeteorJS to elixir (phoenix)

```
iex> x = 1
1
iex> (fn -> x * 2 end).()
2
iex> x
1
```

in the above code `x * 2` only affect inside function, actually I want that edit (inside function) to outside after that function executions

I expecting `x = 1`initially and x= 2 after that function execution

How can I do like multiple global variable edit inside a function in elixir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant itself change the value of a variable inside a function. You can assign your variable the return value of the function

```
x = (fn -> x * 2 end).()
```

To get multiple variables you could return a tuple or list

```
{x,y} = (fn -> {x * 2, y * 4}  end).()
```

This is due to the way scoping works in elixir. You can think of functions running in their own environments, which include variables.

When you  declared variable `x=1` it was given in say "global console" environment. When you define the function, variable `x` is available to this function. But you must remember that this function executes in its own environment. Any changes made to the variable is effective only in this function's environment and hence you do not see changes in the "global console" environment.
If you like you can store the result of executing this function as shown above

Its a concept called immutability that elixir and many functional like languages follow. [From the docs](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-types.html) :-

By being immutable, Elixir code is easier to reason about as you never need to worry if a particular code is mutating your data structure in place.

By being immutable, Elixir also helps eliminate common cases where concurrent code has race conditions because two different entities are trying to change a data structure at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

This is a scoping issue which I have explained in [Fill a List with a for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33830686/fill-a-list-with-a-for-loop). There is a specific mention of this in the getting started guide http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-types.html#anonymous-functions

You need to rebind the value to the result of the function. This is because functions run in their own scope.

```
iex> x = 1
1
iex> x = (fn -> x * 2 end).()
2
iex> x
2
```

You are not globally editing the variable. You are rebinding to a new value. All references to x prior to the rebinding would still refer to the old value (1).

Comment: @lintocheeran I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Please could you be more detailed?