# elixir fill a list with for loop

Tags: for-loop, elixir

I wanted to fill a list with for-loop. I cheked this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33830686/fill-a-list-with-a-for-loop) which has reason for why below code won't do it but then what will be my code to achieve it. I am newbie to elixir and from Java background

```
old_data = ['a','b','c','d']
new_data = []
for data <- old_data do
  new_data = List.insert_at(new_data, -1, data)
  IO.puts(new_data)
end
IO.puts(old_data)
IO.puts("new data is #{new_data}.")
```

There are few manipulations I have to do before adding elements to `new_data` so `new_data = old_data` is not something I am looking for

Comment: `new_data = old_data` would be more concise

Comment: The code won’t do it because of scoping.

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff: Thank you for the input. There are few manipulations I have to do before add elements to `new_data` so `new_data = old_data` is not something I am looking for.

Comment: Ouch, I missed the fact that `new_data` is appending the elements, returning _not reversed_ list. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

*Elixir* is (unlike Java) immutable. That said, one *cannot* modify any data inplace. Also, there is no *for loop*. There are no loops at all. [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#for/1) is **a comprehension**.

That said, if you want to *produce* new list, you should do it explicitly. Unfortunately, it is impossible with `Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`. We usually use a recursion for that.

```rb
defmodule Reverser do
  def go(input, output \\ [])                  # header
  def go([], output), do: Enum.reverse(output) # termination
  def go([h | t], output), do: go(t, [h | output])
end

Reverser.go([1, 2, 3])
#⇒ [1, 2, 3]
```

Also, here we use [`Enum.reverse/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html?#reverse/1) at termination because we *prepended* to the list during recursion, which is a way faster approach compared to *append* for linked lists.

---

*Sidenote:* `IO.puts/1` output could be confusing, use [`IO.inspect/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/IO.html?#inspect/3) instead:

```rb
IO.inspect([1, 2, 3], label: "List")
#⇒ List: [1, 2, 3]
```

---

*Sidenote #2:* `['a','b','c','d']` *is a list of lists*. If you want a list of chars / strings, use *double quotes*. Yes, the meaning of single quotes and double quotes is drastically different.

```rb
is_list('a')
#⇒ true
'a' == [97]
#⇒ true
```

Answer (score 4):

Aleksei mentioned a good starting point, however once you learn how recursions work, you can make your code cleaner by using [`Enum`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html) functions like [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2), of course it depends on situation:

```
old_data = ['a','b','c','d']
Enum.map(old_data, fn _el -> -1 end)
#⇒ [-1, -1, -1, -1]
```

Comment: Also `Enum.reduce/3` as a swiss knife :)

Comment: Indeed, especially since elixir is dynamically typed