# While Loop in Elixir by re-assigning a value to a variable

Tags: loops, while-loop, elixir

I want to encode this algorithm In Elixir:

```
var name = generate_name();
while (check_if_exists(name)) {
  name = generate_name();
}
```

I can't encode that the same way in Elixir because there must more idiomatic and functional way. How can I do that then?

Comment: One approach is to try to convert your algorithm  into map/list processing.  Can either `generate_name()` or `check_if_exists()` be implemented as processing a map/list - say a map/list of possible/existing names? Two ways forward and key lookup in a `map` http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/keywords-and-maps.html or a database query using Ecto https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html

Answer (score 8):

Elixir is an [Immutable programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967086/are-elixir-variables-really-immutable). That means you cannot modify the value of variable, only re-bind it. Hence, the *classic* [while-loop](/questions/tagged/while-loop) doesn't exist in Elixir.

**But, you can [implement this using recursion](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/recursion.html):**

```
def get_name do
  name = generate_name()

  case check_if_exists(name) do
    true  -> get_name()
    false -> name
  end
end
```

Comment: Guidelines suggest using `case` for 3+ clauses only: `if check_if_exists(name), do: get_name(), else: name`.

Comment: I can very well change a value of a variable in Elixir

Comment: no, you cannot change the value of a variable - you can only rebind it to a different value.

Comment: If/else is just a macro for the case statement with true/false code above.

Comment: I chose `case` instead of `if-else` because I like it more, even though it's a macro on top of `case` just like @FredtheMagicWonderDog said

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is to create an infinite stream of names, then find the first name that is available:

```
Stream.repeatedly(&generate_name/0)
|> Enum.find(&check_if_exists/1)
```